# How to get the list of displayed items/rows in Vuetify2 VDataTable?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to get the list of displayed items in Vuetify2 VDataTable (after pagination/filtering/sorting, etc)? I need to do some fetching on the visible rows on VDataTable.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the API of [Vuetify2 DataTable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-tables), it can be accessed through the `current-items` event.

```html
<v-data-table
  @current-items="currentItems"
/>
```